# Should we create [gt-m] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, tag-creation-request

I'd like to create tag [gt-m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gt-m) for [GT.M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GT.M).

I get an error message that the tag name is too similar to [gtm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gtm).

Can we create this tag?

GT.M is really the name this product is know under.

GT.M is an implementation of [mumps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mumps).

Comment: I would suggest that [[tag:gtm]] and [[tag:gt.m]] are too similar; disambiguate. This is why the former is a synonym of [[tag:google-tag-manager]].

Comment: I know that it is not optimal. But there are no other name that the GT.M system is know under. The full name is obscure and never used. Because of this I think the name warrants an exception even if it would normally be considered to be too similar.

Comment: Well, maybe `[gtm-database-system]` is okay...

Comment: Caveat: I know nothing of GT.M. Does the M stand for Mumps? If so, would [[tag:gt.mumps]] be appropriate?

Comment: "Does the M stand for Mumps" I don't know! Even the Wikipedia page doesn't give the full name! I don't think `[gt.mumps]` is recognisable. I think `[gtm-database-system]` is better.

Comment: *"I don't know"* The Wikipedia article does seem to imply it is, hence my suggestion: *"GT.M is also an application development platform and a [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler "Compiler") for the [ISO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Organization_for_Standardization "International Organization for Standardization") standard [M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUMPS "MUMPS") language, also known as [MUMPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUMPS "MUMPS"). GT.M, an abbreviation for* Greystone Technology M *..."* So seems the full name is "Greystone Technology MUMPS".

Comment: I missed that! It's right there in the beginning! `[greystone-technology-m]` could be a synonym but I don't it is very recognisable.

Comment: There already is the tag  [gtm-database] that is for exactly this. I am so blind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There already is the tag [gtm-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gtm-database) for exactly this. I don't understand how I managed to miss that one.

I created [gtm-database-system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gtm-database-system) before I found the tag above. It can be removed or set as a synonym.